# confusion while setting environment variable - python flask

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I am struggling to set an environment variable for an api key in a python flask application. I'm using a Mac.

In the terminal I set the environment variable using nano as follows: `nano .bash_profile` and then set my API key: `export API_KEY="xxx"`

However, my default version of python is 3.6, this app is using 3.7 (maybe this is where the confusion is?).

So I tried the following

`nano .bash_profile python3.7` in the terminal then `export API_KEY="xxx"`

When I read this file with `cat .bash_profile python3.7`, it reads:

`export API_KEY="xxx"`

When I try to use this api key in my flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(API_KEY=os.environ.get('API_KEY'))

@app.route("/home")
def home():

    print(app.config)

    render_template('home.html')
```

I reload my home page and `None` is printed in the terminal.

So in the terminal I navigated to that directory and did the following:

```
export API_KEY="xxx"
```

Then printed the contents using `cat .bash_profile python3.7` which prints:

```
export API_KEY="xxx"
export API_KEY="xxx"
```

When I reload my home page, the correct API key value is printed.

Why didn't it work the first time?

Comment: Have you given a try to https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/?

Comment: If you are on a newer mac the default is not bash but zsh. That means that you need to set it in the `.zshrc` file

Comment: I'd also suggest using `zsh`, if you arent already (check with `echo $SHELL`) and the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) plugin, as this is much nicer than bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a walk-through of how to use [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) in the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure). It's fairly straightforward. You put

```
export API_KEY="xxx"
```

in a file named `.env`, and then do `dotenv.load_dotenv()` at some point early on in your app and the contents of `.env` will be available as environment variables.

You'll want to add `.env` to your `.gitignore` so that you don't accidentally save credentials in some place that might be visible.